# The behavior after adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT flag

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to start an activity which will be added into the overview screen (recent task list).

I found this document and follow the guide:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents.html

In activity A, I add "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT" flag to my intent and start activity B with it.

I see both A and B in the list, but when I close activity A, I can still see B in the list. And when I go back to activity B, it seems to be destroyed and create again. (it looks like the activity has been restarted)

My question is:

1. How to automatically close B after I close A?
2. Is there any way to prevent the restarting process?

Answer (score 0):

simply call `finish();` after starting your Activity